# How to convert a Duration like string to a real Duration in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

As the title says, I got a string '01:23.290', it looks like a Duration, but not. Now I need to use this to compare with a real Duration, and I don't how to deal with it. Is there any methods?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use a parsing function like this, then use the comparison methods of `Duration`:

```
Duration parseDuration(String s) {
  int hours = 0;
  int minutes = 0;
  int micros;
  List<String> parts = s.split(':');
  if (parts.length > 2) {
    hours = int.parse(parts[parts.length - 3]);
  }
  if (parts.length > 1) {
    minutes = int.parse(parts[parts.length - 2]);
  }
  micros = (double.parse(parts[parts.length - 1]) * 1000000).round();
  return Duration(hours: hours, minutes: minutes, microseconds: micros);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Package [`duration`](https://pub.dev/packages/duration) provides functions [`parseTime`](https://pub.dev/documentation/duration/latest/duration/parseTime.html) and [`tryParseTime`](https://pub.dev/documentation/duration/latest/duration/tryParseTime.html) to parse duration strings obtained by `Duration().toString()`.

Usage is straight forward:

```dart
print(parseTime(Duration(hours: 5, seconds: 10, milliseconds: 567).toString()));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
List<String> timeParts = time.split(':');

Duration duration = Duration(hours: int.parse(timeParts[0]), minutes: int.parse(timeParts[1]), seconds: int.parse(timeParts[2]));
```

Comment: Much better than using a package by an unverified uploader, and almost works for reverting Duration.toString(), also nicely short, int.parse(timeParts[2]) may cause issues with the microseconds from Duration.toString() however.

Answer (score 2):

Another way using DateTime and DateFormat:

```
Duration durationParse(String time) {
  final ts = DateFormat('y-MM-dd').format(DateTime.now());
  final dt = DateTime.parse('$ts $time');
  return Duration(hours: dt.hour, minutes: dt.minute, seconds: dt.second);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  String durationString = '2:30:45'; // Example duration string
  
  Duration duration = parseDuration(durationString);
  
  print(duration); // Outputs: 2:30:45.000000
  
  // You can access individual components of the duration if needed
  print(duration.inHours); // Outputs: 2
  print(duration.inMinutes); // Outputs: 150
  print(duration.inSeconds); // Outputs: 9045
}

Duration parseDuration(String durationString) {
  List<String> components = durationString.split(':');
  
  int hours = int.parse(components[0]);
  int minutes = int.parse(components[1]);
  int seconds = int.parse(components[2]);
  
  return Duration(hours: hours, minutes: minutes, seconds: seconds);
}
```