# String is not a subtype of duration in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting an error from my `fromJson()` method in flutter:

```
  factory ReminderModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ReminderModel(
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
        dayName: json["dayName"] == null ? null : json["dayName"],
        workStartTime: DateTime.parse(json["workStartTime"]),
        workEndTime: DateTime.parse(
          json["workEndTime"],
        ),
        singleReminderModel: json["singleReminderModel"] == null
            ? null
            : List<SingleReminderModel>.from(
                json["singleReminderModel"].map(
                  (x) => x.toString(),
                ),
              ),
        frequency: json["frequency"] == null ? null : json["frequency"],
        breakPeriod: json["isPending"] == null ? null : json["breakPeriod"],
      );
```

My model looks like this:

```
  int? id;
  String? dayName;
  DateTime? workStartTime;
  DateTime? workEndTime;
  List<SingleReminderModel>? singleReminderModel;
  Duration? frequency;
  Duration? breakPeriod;

  ReminderModel({
    this.id,
    this.dayName,
    this.workStartTime,
    this.workEndTime,
    this.singleReminderModel,
    this.frequency,
    this.breakPeriod,
  });
```

I need to accurately save the `duration` to `string` and back to `duration`.

I got no error when I saved the data like this inside my `toJson()` method

```
"frequency": frequency!.toString(),
```

**update: **
After the suggested edits I'm getting this error:

[image]

Comment: You need cast to `Duration` , can you add toJson?

Comment: How would I add the cast? Can you provide an example?
Yes I can add toJson

Comment: Then add, please, so that I can be sure about answer.  At `json["frequency"] as Duration()`.

Comment: done please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Output**
[image]

To parse Duration from String
use this method. Place it outside this class,

```dart
Duration parseDuration(String s) {
  int hours = 0;
  int minutes = 0;
  int micros;
  List<String> parts = s.split(':');
  if (parts.length > 2) {
    hours = int.parse(parts[parts.length - 3]);
  }
  if (parts.length > 1) {
    minutes = int.parse(parts[parts.length - 2]);
  }
  micros = (double.parse(parts[parts.length - 1]) * 1000000).round();
  return Duration(hours: hours, minutes: minutes, microseconds: micros);
}
```

convert like

```
  frequency:
            json["frequency"] == null ? null : parseDuration(json["frequency"]),
        breakPeriod: json["isPending"] == null
            ? null
            : parseDuration(json["breakPeriod"]),
```

**FullWidget+Everything**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WidgetTest extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final ReminderModel model = ReminderModel(
                  id: 1,
                  dayName: "sunDay",
                  workEndTime: DateTime.now(),
                  workStartTime: DateTime.now(),
                  frequency: Duration(seconds: 4),
                  breakPeriod: Duration(minutes: 12),
                );
                final json = model.toJson();

                print(json.toString());
                final ReminderModel m = ReminderModel.fromJson(json);

                print("id from model: ${m.id}");
              },
              child: Text("FR"))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TableJson {
  final String value1 = "1";
}

class ReminderModel {
  int? id;
  String? dayName;
  DateTime? workStartTime;
  DateTime? workEndTime;
  // List<SingleReminderModel>? singleReminderModel;
  Duration? frequency;
  Duration? breakPeriod;

  ReminderModel({
    this.id,
    this.dayName,
    this.workStartTime,
    this.workEndTime,
    this.frequency,
    this.breakPeriod,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "dayName": dayName!,
        "workStartTime": workStartTime!.toIso8601String(),
        "workEndTime": workEndTime!.toIso8601String(),
        // "workHour": workHour!.toString(),
        // "singleRemindeModel": singleReminderModel == null
        //     ? null
        //     : List<dynamic>.from(
        //         singleReminderModel!.map(
        //           (e) => e.toJson(),
        //         ),
        //       ),
        "frequency": frequency!.toString(),
        "breakPeriod": breakPeriod!.toString(),
      };

  factory ReminderModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ReminderModel(
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
        dayName: json["dayName"] == null ? null : json["dayName"],
        workStartTime: DateTime.parse(json["workStartTime"]),
        workEndTime: DateTime.parse(
          json["workEndTime"],
        ),
        frequency:
            json["frequency"] == null ? null : parseDuration(json["frequency"]),
        breakPeriod: json["isPending"] == null
            ? null
            : parseDuration(json["breakPeriod"]),
      );
}

Duration parseDuration(String s) {
  int hours = 0;
  int minutes = 0;
  int micros;
  List<String> parts = s.split(':');
  if (parts.length > 2) {
    hours = int.parse(parts[parts.length - 3]);
  }
  if (parts.length > 1) {
    minutes = int.parse(parts[parts.length - 2]);
  }
  micros = (double.parse(parts[parts.length - 1]) * 1000000).round();
  return Duration(hours: hours, minutes: minutes, microseconds: micros);
}
```

Does thing produce any errors?

ref: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54853311/10157127)

Comment: Tried this I'm getting a `Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid double` error

Comment: i think you are getting from `SingleReminderModel`. can you add that model as well.

Comment: Single reminder model only has an integer and date time which is properly formatted and separately gets saved to dB. It does not throw any errors

Comment: I updated my answer, check if it produces any errors for you?

Answer (score 0):

**Try doing it like this**

```
factory ReminderModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ReminderModel(
        ...
        frequency: Duration(microseconds: json["frequency"] ?? 0),
        breakPeriod: json["isPending"] == null ? null : Duration(microseconds: json["breakPeriod"] ?? 0),
      );
```

**To JSON function**

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        ...
        "frequency": frequency!.inMilliseconds,
        "breakPeriod": breakPeriod!.inMilliseconds,
      }
```

Comment: didn't work still getting the String is not a subtype of int error

Comment: You should delete the old documents first, because you already have some docs in database that contain "frequency" and "breakPeriod" as Strings not numbers