# Time with flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime, timer

I am totally new with flutter and I do not understand how can I resolve a problem.
I'm actually working to a kart race app and:

1. I need to read a string like 1:02.456
2. Convert in some kind of time
3. Compare with another string similar to first one
4. Go to do something

es:

```
blap = null;
if(1:02.456 < 1:03.589){
    blap = '1:02.456';
} else {
    blap = '1:03.589;
}
```

I read on the web that I ca use the class DateTime, but every time I try to convert the string in an object of that class, I do not get wat I want.

There is a better way?
Thank you.

Comment: I suspect you want to parse durations, not times.  `DateTime` represents a moment in time and would be inappropriate.  I would just parse the string with a regular expression, use `int.parse` on each component, and combine the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds appropriately.

Comment: I'm sure there are other questions about parsing `Duration`s from `String`s, but here is one: [String is not a subtype of duration in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68679539/179715)

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on a kart race app probably you need to use Duration, not DateTime.

This is one way to convert a string like yours into Duration

```
 Duration parseDuration(String s) {
  int hours = 0;
  int minutes = 0;
  int micros;
  List<String> parts = s.split(':');
  if (parts.length > 2) {
    hours = int.parse(parts[parts.length - 3]);
  }
  if (parts.length > 1) {
    minutes = int.parse(parts[parts.length - 2]);
  }
  micros = (double.parse(parts[parts.length - 1]) * 1000000).round();
  return Duration(hours: hours, minutes: minutes, microseconds: micros);
}
```

Then, to compare two Duration in the way you wanted, this is an example:

```
String blap;
Duration time1=Duration(hours: 1),time2=Duration(hours: 2);
if(time1.compareTo(time2)<0){
  //time2 is greater than time1
  blap=time1.toString();
}else{
  blap=time2.toString();
}
```